# Does gradient descent assume updates of one layer/parameter at a time?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I read the following in ["Deep Learning", from Goodfellow et al (Chapter 8, page 313)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html):

> The gradient tells how to update each parameter, *under the
>   assumption that the other layers do **not** change. In practice, we update*
>   all of the layers simultaneously.
>
> When we make the update, unexpected results can happen because many
>   functions composed together are changed simultaneously, using updates
>   that were computed under the assumption that the other functions
>   remain constant.

How is that possible? Isn't gradient descent based on the fact that a function decreases **fastest** if we move in the direction of the **negative gradient**, and across all weights precisely **at the same time**?

Comment: Did you try a thought experiment where you consider what happens in a two-layer neural network as the weights are updated?

Comment: @NeilG Thanks - Yes and in e.g. SGD we don't update the weights until we are done computing the gradient against every parameter (i.e. we indeed update all of the layers simultaneously). What confuses me is the statement _"the gradient tells how to update each parameter under the **assumption** that the other layers do not change"_. Isn't that incorrect?

Comment: No, that is correct provided you're not using second order methods.  They're partial derivatives, right?

Comment: @NeilG Not sure I follow, yes the gradient is comprised of partial derivatives, but it still gives the fastest direction of change if we were to move all variables (at the same time) in its direction, doesn't it? And either way, why would the gradient tell us how to update each parameter assuming that the other layers do *not* change? Just because _we can compute it_ by taking partial derivatives independently for each parameter, I don't see how that leads to the assumption that we are supposed to move the parameters one by one.

Comment: "why would the gradient tell us how to update each parameter assuming that the other layers do not change?" Because it *is* a partial derivative, so that's by definition.

Comment: @NeilG No, absolutely not - the gradient is the direction of steepest descent. That is, it is the best way of updating the weights, *simultaneously*. Now yes, it so happens that this steepest descent direction is given by the vector of partial derivatives, but this is just a counterintuitive mathematical surprise, that the best way to update the weights *simultaneously* happens to be obtained by pretending we change them one at a time.  But at the end of the day it's *still* the direction of steepest descent. Without further context the quoted passage in Goodfellow really makes no sense.

Comment: I added an answer to clarify your confusion.

Comment: Suppose you want to minimize x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+..... Gradient gives direction towards the minimum, so take step in that direction. For more general situation, direction towards the minimum is instead given by Newton step.  "Gradient" step is a super cheap approximation to Newton step in a sense that it lies in the same halfplane, so you can still make progress

Answer (score 1):

Gradient descent using first order methods makes the assumption of a locally symmetric paraboloid loss with known curvature (the learning rate). In other words, we are taking a second order Taylor approximation and fixing the second order terms as given.  Then, the only values that need to be evaluated are the first order coefficients, which is the vector of partial derivatives.

If instead you were using second order methods, then you are no longer assuming the curvature.  Yes, the function decreases fastest if we move in the direction of the negative gradient.  However, it's better to move more quickly in directions where the curvature is small (since the minimum is far in these directions), and more slowly when the curvature is large (to prevent overshooting the minimum in these directions).

Comment: Regarding: ""the fact that a function decreases fastest if we move in the direction of the negative gradient") is no longer true". Actually, the gradient does indeed give the steepest ascent direction in all cases *for sufficiently small step sizes*. The second order direction gives more descent for step sizes implied by the Hessian we are using.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks for the correcting me!  Yes, for tiny step sizes, you can just follow the gradient since it is fastest, but you'll never get anywhere with tiny step sizes.  I will clarify my answer.